# how to get wp-content folder in wordpress?

Tags: php, directory, path, include

if my **main.php** file is located inside `/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/folder/folder/folder/`
why including **urls.php** , located inside `/wp-content/uploads/folder/` doesn't work with this path:

```
include_once("../../../../../uploads/folder/urls.php");
```

it works only if placed inside same folder as main.php with path `('urls.php');`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

you can use `content_url()` it's located with `http://www.example.com/wp-content` wp-content folder.

Or for path

you can use `WP_CONTENT_DIR` it'll located to `wp-content` folder.

```
require_once(WP_CONTENT_DIR. 'uploads/folder/urls.php');
```

Check more info [Documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories)

Comment: still not sure why the multiple ../ doesn't work but thanks, with the WP_CONTENT_DIR works

Comment: @NathanBernard
Script is actually executed in other files which including the file. It may be the site index.php, or wp-admin index.php, or anyone. It's dynamic, so `../` or `./` type relative path will get wrong. Try to put `$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]` into script and echo out, that will see the actual runing file.

Comment: It seems that `WP_CONTENT_DIR` doesn't have a trailing slash, at least in my install. Not sure if this is a recent change, but I just got an error trying to load `wp-contentvendor/...`. Heads up.

Comment: On my context (server? WordPress version? phph version?) `WP_CONTENT_DIR` doesn't have the trailing slash, so I have to write `require_once(WP_CONTENT_DIR. '/uploads/folder/urls.php');`

Answer (score 1):

It seems strange. Do you have any error message when you run your main.php?
Try to check again, maybe a typo somewhere. Do you take help of Text editor auto-completion when calling urls.php?